# Classification tips for a begginer

Tags: classification, predictive-models, prediction, naive-bayes, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm doing a graduation work that involves applying Classification algorithms in a dataset of matches from Dota 2 (a popular MOBA game). Here's an explanation of the problem:

Dota 2 matches are played by two teams of 5 members in a 5x5 manner. Each player can choose from a pool of 106 playable characters that are called "Heroes". Each hero can only be picked once in a match (there is never two same heroes in a match). The deal is that the hero picking  have a major influence on the match outcome, since certains heroes have synergies with others, at the same time that some heroes are direct counters for others heroes.

What I'm trying to do is predict the game outcome based on the heroes picked for each team. Right now I'm using .csv files exported from my database containing 11 nominal atributes, the one that represents the winner team is the class, and the other ten are the hero picks. I tried several algorithms and the one that got the highest accuracy was Naive Bayes, with ~ 72%. Next was K-NN with around 65% correct classifications. I've got about 100.000 matches in my database.

Is there any way to improve this? I'm really new to Machine-Learning/KDD. I'm using Weka for the mining. Here's an example of how I'm organizing my data in the .csv.

winner,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5
0,40,48,13,37,51,47,102,30,41,69

R means *Radiant* and D means *Dire*, which are the names of the teams used in the game.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the "Engrish"!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be relatively feature poor in my opinion. There are many traits which are well known to be important in Dota that you might want to include in explicitly.

For example:

1. How many supports/carries does r/d have?
2. There are some hero combinations that are known to be powerful (tiny+wisp comes to mind) and it might be worth including an indicators of these events.

I would suggest really thinking what you know about the data and trying to use some domain knowledge to inform feature creation. Of course make sure to have set up training/validation/test sets so that you ensure your features aren't just pretending to help predict.